# Rails updating column rows for has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have added `iconfolio` to my character model. Each character `has_one :iconfolio`.

**character.rb**

```
has_one :iconfolio, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :iconfolio
before_validation do
 self.create_iconfolio unless iconfolio
end
```

Here is the migration file:

```
class CreateIconfolios < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :iconfolios do |t|
      t.integer :character_id

      t.string :icon_url

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :iconfolios, :character_id
  end
end
```

The iconfolio class:

**iconfolio.rb**

```
class Iconfolio < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :character

  validates :character_id, presence: true

  before_create do
    self.icon_url = '/assets/icon1.png'
  end

end
```

Firstly, how do I ensure an `iconfolio` has been created for each `character`?

Secondly, how do I update all the rows in the `character_id` column? The `character_id` value is different for every `iconfolio` record. Updating the `icon_url` column can be  done in the console:

```
Iconfolio.all.update_all(person_normal_icon_url: '/assets/icon1.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a default template iconfolio and `update_all` character records as you did with Iconfolio.  If your database isn't already large you can iterate through `Character.all` and assign them an iconfolio.  Be advised this will instantiate an object per row and be much more time consuming than update_all.  The benefit of instantiating them is it will not bypass your validations. Write a block in your console that iterates through each record and finds or creates an iconfolio per character like:

```
  Character.all.find_each do |char|
     if char.iconfolio.blank?
          Iconfolio.create(character_id: char.id, whatever_other_params: put_here)
     end
  end
```

Then make an after_create in your Character model that creates and assigns an iconfolio for future new characters.  Something like:

```
after_create :make_an_iconfolio

def make_an_iconfolio
   Iconfolio.create(character_id: self.id, other params here)
end
```

As a sidenote, the Rails way to add a relationship in your create_table migration is:

```
def change
    create_table :iconfolios do |t|
      t.belongs_to :character, index: true
```

This just makes it more clear to you and others that it's a relationship and saves an extra line of code from indexing.